# An exercise about homology group

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm now learning algebraic topology and I met an exercise below.

We have transformations listed below in 3-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}$<sup>3</sup>:
$$\begin{align}
& S:(x,y,z)\mapsto (x+1,-y,z)\\
& T:(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y+1,z)\\
& U:(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,x+y,z+1)
\end{align}
$$

(1)We denote the group generated by S and T by K. What is the homology group with integer coefficients H$_*(N;\mathbb{Z})$for the quotient space N=$\mathbb{R}$<sup>3</sup>/K ?

(2)We denote the group generated by S,T and U by G. What is the homology group with integer coefficients H$_*(M;\mathbb{Z})$for the quotient space M=$\mathbb{R}$<sup>3</sup>/G ?

I'm puzzled about the groups generated by these transformations. What exactly they are?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for only $H_1$?

Comment: Anyway, (1) is Klein bottle.

Comment: I'm sorry for ambiguous description. I think it is not just for 1. It asks for H$_n, n\in \mathbb{N}$